# New window form in a c# program

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to open a new window form  on a button click

In main program's constructor I've got:

```
form_targeting = new Targeting();
```

In button1_Click(...) there is:

```
form_targeting.Show();
```

and ofc in main program's fields there's

```
public static Targeting form_targeting;
```

When opening first time, It works correctly. After closing 2nd window and pressing the button in a 1st window again, I get error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Targeting'.

I've added that into Targeting class but it still doesn't work:

```
        private void Targeting_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
```

It works now, I had to write completely the same but using designer :p
thanks guys :)

Comment: what happens when you move `form_targeting = new Targeting();` to the button click, not so sure as why you would need `static Targeting`

Comment: How are you closing the `Targeting` form?

Comment: @Odded im closing it with x (top right corner) [at]V4Vendetta then it works, but isnt that creating new object all the time?

Comment: @Patryk yes it would be, in that case you could `Hide` and then again `Show` up the form

Comment: @V4Vendetta, is there any way to replace (x) funcionality from closing object to hiding it?

Comment: @Patryk Check on what marek mentions just add a check for `CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing` and then hide the form there like `this.Hide()` that should do it for you

Comment: Ok I've got it, I just got a problem with naming that method :D :P DUnno what should be it's name, Targeting_Closing Targeting_Close or wot? :p (edited question with the code ive used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the form calls `Dispose` on it. You need to write a handler for the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event. In that event handler call `Hide` on your form instance and set `e.Cancel = true` so that the form is not closed.

Answer (score 2):

Put the code into button click event.

```
button1_Click(...)
{
   form_targeting = new Targeting();
   form_targeting.Show();
}
```

End close form by

```
form_targeting.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code means, you are initializing a instance of Targeting from.

```
 form_targeting = new Targeting();
```

Once you show the form using following code `form_targeting.Show();` and close the form by clicking on the cross button or in any way. The memory initialize to form_targeting  variable in first form is get freed.

So second time, you try to open same form, it raises error.